# SSIS 2012: Get row of each group-by-aggregation

Tags: ssis

In a Data Flow I get the data with a Script Component that queries a webservice. The output is a table with payments from customers.

```
| PaymentId | CustomerId | Amount | PaymentDate |
| 2         | 1          | 10     | 01/01/2009  |
| 5         | 1          | 15     | 08/07/2013  |
| 1         | 2          | 20     | 05/08/2007  |
| 3         | 2          | 18     | 07/03/2011  |
| 6         | 2          | 32     | 02/09/2013  |
| 4         | 3          | 70     | 04/06/2012  |
| 7         | 3          | 61     | 02/03/2013  |
```

Among other things, I have to filter out following rows per customer:

- the payment with largest amount
- the payment with smallest amount
- the first payment
- the most recent payment

And for each I need the PaymentId, CustomerId, Amount and PaymentDate for later processing.

I know how to use the Aggregate Transforamtion, group by CustomerId and use the appropriate Min/Max functions to get the requested VALUES.

But what is the best approach to get the complete ROWS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're data source is a SQL database, do what you can with SQL, before you get to SSIS. This will generally give you the best performance.

Otherwise, suggest dumping data from the web service into a `RAW` file. Raw files are quite useful for staging data to do assorted transformations. [more on RAW files](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-raw-files-are-awesome-131/)

Comment: Though I have currently access to the underlying SQL-Server database, this will probably change in the future when migrating to a ISV-hosted version. Then I will only have access via webservice-api. Therefore I want to design the ETL independently from direct access to the database, accepting the performance penalty.

Comment: Sorry, I focused on the last part of the question and forgot about the first sentence mentioning the web service. Another path would be extracting data from the web server and putting it into a `RAW` file. I find RAW files very handy for staging data while doing assorted transformations. [link to info on raw files](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-raw-files-are-awesome-131/)

Comment: Just to be sure if I take your point: I put the data retrieved from the webservice into a RAW file and then use this file as a data flow source. Then I can write appropriate SQL statements against this file to get the required rows.
If from your experience that’s the most efficient solution to my case, I will give it a try!

Comment: You can't do SQL statements on the RAW files. Use SQL if you could connect directly to the database. Otherwise yes, dump the web service data into a RAW file and use the RAW file as your data flow source. The RAW file meta data is native to SSIS, thus making subsequent transformations more efficient.

Comment: Then the solution to my case seems to be: Create a staging table and use this as an OLE DB Source to be able to run the sql queries?

Comment: That could be a path. But I started using RAW files to get away from creating tables dedicated to staging. Best practices I've been taught preach doing as much in SQL as you can, after than use the SSIS transformations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33488/discussion-between-mike-henderson-and-heribert)